# how to configure visual studio pro's text editor for editing a .swift file?

Tags: swift, visual-studio

I do my editing for Xcode Swift source with Visual Studio on windows, which remotes into my Mac and Xcode.

When editing a .swift file, VS does pretty good, and correctly colors keywords.

But some commands don't work right:
comment and uncomment,
constantly pops up the [abc] help menu, which annoyingly obscures the source code,
new window command is not available.

I can't find a setting within Options > Text Editor to control this. And no StackO answers have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not support development on other devices than macOS.
Be happy that it works the way you describe it. Simply I would recommend to work on your Mac.

But if you want really to work on windows for native Swift development I would recommend to remote your Mac in a Windows window where you can use Xcode. [Microsoft Instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-mac)

Or instead of `Visual Studio Pro` try `Visual Studio Code` there are some free plugins which support the Swift Language. (e.g. Plugin: Swift Language)

[image: Plugins Visual Studio Code]